# Getting a null exception error, but the variable this is thrown on is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a form to add a record to a database, that is prepopulated with the values from an existing record. When I click the save button however a null exception error is being thrown on the first variable used, which I know has a value. I have even tried typing over the pre-populated value and still get the null exception error. Why would this happen?

Here is the item from the aspx page:

```
<asp:tablecell>
   <asp:textbox ID="txt_author" runat="server" Text='<%#Item.Author %>' ></asp:textbox>
</asp:tablecell>
```

Here is the line throwing the error on the code behind:

```
protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string vAuthor = txt_author.Text;
```

Comment: When you say you "know" it has a value - have you validated that in the debugger?

Comment: No, not sure how to validate in debugger (new to programming this sort of thing)... I can look at the form and see the value of txt_author, I can even change that value, so I know that that field on the form is not null.

Comment: `txt_author` is null, not `txt_author.Text`.

Comment: You put a breakpoint at that line, run the web app in the debugger, and look at the value of the variable at the *exact* line that will throw an exception.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to be a binding issue.

Comment: How you came to know that this line has an error ?

Comment: You have to call find control on the control container. The textbox is inside an asp:tablecell. You need to declare the textbox first, then you can access it.

Comment: Kramb, could you provide a code example of how to declare the textbox for this situation, again still very new to this and examples help (a lot).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ASP Table ID will be `Table1` and having one row and TextBox is present in first cell, You can modify As per your code.

```
 string vAuthor= (Table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("txt_author") as TextBox).Text
```

Since your Text Box is Present in Table Structure, and we can not able access it directly, we need to find Control first from TableCell.

Comment: JayDipJ, your solution is not working for me. First the .Text at the end is not recognized, second when I drop that I get a cannot convert error, so convert the reference to table1.txt_author to a string,,, and still get a null reference error.

Comment: @BrentOliver I have just Updated it,Since there is Missing Opening bracket `(` at the begining

Comment: still getting an error when running "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." One thing I noticed on this form vs the original submission form is that the designer.cs did not generate records for any of the controls and I had to add them all manually to the code behind page, maybe this is causing an additional issue?

Comment: @BrentOliver Confirm that Index of Row and cell is correct in your case and there is no issue while you adding it manually or from designer

Comment: Guess I can't figure out how to reference that Index. It is the first row and second column of the table. I have tried [0] for the row and [1] for the column, and also [1],[2] and still throwing same error? Sorry very new to coding in these languages and feeling my way through everything.

Comment: Have figured out what I needed thanks to your answer. The table that I am using is inside of a formview that is retrieving the record, so I had to change your suggestion to:       string vAuthor = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_author") as TextBox).Text;